# SQL column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle11g

I have a problem in this code:

```
select idingrediente
into niding
from ingredientes 
inner join RECHASING on ingredientes.IDINGREDIENTE = RECHASING.IDINGREDIENTE
inner join receta on RECHASING.RIDRECETA = receta.IDRECETA;
```

Error:

> Column ambiguously defined

Table **ingredientes**:

- idingrediente
- ingrediente
- cantingrediente

Table **rechasing**:

- idingrediente
- idreceta

Table **receta**:

- idReceta
- Cantingrediente

`rechasing` is a intermediate table because `receta` has n:n `ingredientes`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give aliases to your tables, then identify the `idingrediente` column with an alias:

```
SELECT t1.idingrediente      -- or t2.idingrediente
INTO niding
FROM ingredientes t1
INNER JOIN rechasing t2
    ON t1.idingrediente = t2.idingrediente
INNER JOIN receta t3
    ON t2.ridreceta = t3.idreceta
```